# Evenly spread values

Tags: code-golf

Given a sorted list of unique positive floats (none of which are integers) such as:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.2]
```

Evenly spread out the values that fall between two consecutive integers. So in this case you would get:

```
[0.333, 0.666, 1.5, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.5]
```

(I have truncated the values 1/3 and 2/3 for ease of presentation.)

Comment: Can the input have repeats?

Comment: @xnor No, I edited the question

Comment: I think there should be more than one test case.

Answer (score 8):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 8 bytes

```
kŢᵉR→/+j
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6Fmuzjy56uLUz6FHbJH3trCXFScnFUJkFNzWjDfUNDXSMQIShCZhpDCYhbFMQaQySjYXoAAA)

Input and output are both in fractions, because Nekomata doesn't have floating point numbers.

```
kŢᵉR→/+j
k           Floor
                e.g. [1/10,2/10,14/10,23/10,24/10,25/10,32/10] -> [0,0,1,2,2,2,3]
 Ţ          Tally; returns a list of unique elements and a list of their counts
                e.g. [0,0,1,2,2,2,3] -> [0,1,2,3], [2,1,3,1]
  ᵉR        Range each count, and push the original list
                e.g. [2,1,3,1] -> [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3],[1]], [2,1,3,1]
    →       Increment
                e.g. [2,1,3,1] -> [3,2,4,2]
     /      Divide
                e.g. [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3],[1]], [3,2,4,2] -> [[1/3,2/3],[1/2],[1/4,1/2,3/4],[1/2]]
      +     Add
                e.g. [0,1,2,3], [[1/3,2/3],[1/2],[1/4,1/2,3/4],[1/2]] -> [[1/3,2/3],[3/2],[9/4,5/2,11/4],[7/2]]
       j    Join
                e.g. [[1/3,2/3],[3/2],[9/4,5/2,11/4],[7/2]] -> [1/3,2/3,3/2,9/4,5/2,11/4,7/2]
```

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(x)sequence(y<-rle(t<-x%/%1)$l)/rep(y+1,y)+t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHq1LLUvOKCotTEFNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KjSLUwtLU_OSUzUqbXSLclI1Smx0K1T1VQ01VXI09YtSCzQqtQ11KjW1S6CaDBDmaCRrGOgZ6igY6BnpKBjqmegoGOkZgwgwy1RHwVjPSFMTom_BAggNAA)

A rare use for R's obscure `sequence` function: "For each element of `x` the sequence `1...x` is created. These are concatenated and the result returned."

The documentation also notes: "`sequence` mainly exists in reverence to the very early history of R."

Comment: [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHq1LLUvOKCotTEFNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KjSLUwtLU_OSUzUqbXSLclI1Smx0K1T1VQ01VXI09YtSCzQqtQ11KjW1S6CaDBDmaCRrGOgZ6igY6BnpKBjqmegoGOkZgwgwy1RHwVjPSFMTom_BAggNAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```apl
∊⌊(⊂⊣+⍋⍤⊢÷≢⍤,)⌸⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FH16OeLo1HXU2PuhZrP@rtftS75FHXosPbH3UuAjJ1NB/17ADy/6c9apvwqLfvUVfzo941j3q3HFpv/Kht4qO@qcFBzkAyxMMz@H@agoGeIRAbKRjqmSgY6RkDMYg2VTDWMwIA) (Using Extended because TIO is out of date)

`⌊(`…`)⌸⊢` on each unique floor (`⌊`) and its corresponding argument elements (`⊢`):

`⊂` enclose the

`⊣` left argument, i.e. the floor in question

`+` added to

`⍋⍤⊢` the grade (`⍋` sorting permutation: 1…length) of (`⍤`) the right argument (`⊢` the elements)

`÷` divided by

`≢⍤,` the count (`≢`) of (`⍤`) the concatenation (`,`) of the floor and the elements

`∊` **e**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ïγεā¤>/+}˜
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Ppzm89tPdJ4aImdvnbt6Tn//0cb6BnqKBjoGekoGOqZ6CgY6RmDCDDLVEfBWM8oFgA) or [try it online with step-by-step debug-lines](https://tio.run/##bZC9TsMwEMd3nuKUqVVNaFJYkKBCqkAMPEHV4RofiZFrB38UMXTgPRjZGRA8QGFD6iulsRMQA4vl@/rd/f/a4lJQ0yTXqvbuFBJ2tv2YHiSXUmsTws/XLnFltK8B@R0WpBzQvUcJa5SebGjbvXVtN1gDYVGB04Awz5gkVbpqcWhQlcRBChu3zHbvX08b1qHJgasIJFoHwtEKBjGMk0PQt5HIABUHoQpDq/aCX8j25bznzMRacIqo/xfD8rGtCguDrjjKhn8xRz3ngvMI6dQFJSEqvDFBeRmMiJL7qdHmxzJ0jhSDh0q0BrRrtDdgyHoZr/1@njbNfJxmDMZpziBLjxnk6SQ88XfCYJLmiz0).

**Explanation:**

```python
ï         # Floor all values in the (implicit) input-list
 γ        # Group it into adjacent equal values
  ε       # Map over each group:
   ā      #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list)
    ¤     #  Push its last item - the length (without popping the list)
     >    #  Increase this length by 1
      /   #  Divide all values in the [1,length]-ranged list by this (length+1)
       +  #  Add it to each floored value of the current group
  }˜      # After the map: flatten the list of lists
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: A port of [_@alephalpha_'s Nekomata answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263921/52210) is 10 bytes as well: `ïÅγDLs>/+˜` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8PrDrec2u/gU2@lrn57z/3@0gZ6hjoKBnpGOgqGeiY6CkZ4xiACzTHUUjPWMYgE).

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 45 bytes

```matlab
@(x)(t=fix(x))+sum(triu(u=t==t'))./(sum(u)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0JTo8Q2LbMCyNDULi7N1SgpyizVKLUtsbUtUdfU1NPXAAmWamobav6vULBViDbQM9RRMNAz0lEw1DPRUTDSMwYRYJapjoKxnlGsNVca0LT/AA)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(x)(t=fix(x))+sum(triu(u=t==t'))./(sum(u)+1)

@(x)                                           % Anonymuous function
    (t=fix(x))                                 % t: round down x, element-wise
                        u=t==t'                % u: matrix of pairwise comparisons of t
                   triu(       )               % Upper triangular part of u
               sum(            )               % Sum of each column of that
                                    sum(u)+1   % Sum of each column of u, plus 1
                                 ./(        )  % Divide, elemment-wise
              +                                % Add, element-wise
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ḞJ÷L‘$+Ʋƙ`F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnleh7f7PGqYoaJ9bNOxmQlu////jzbQM9RRMNAz0lEw1DPRUTDSMwYRYJapjoKxnlEsAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 95 bytes

```python
lambda x:[k+~j/~len(i)for k,[*i]in groupby(x,int)for j in range(len(i))]
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc1BDoIwEAXQvaeYZau1QmvRmHgSrAYixSq0pNZENl7EDYnRO3kbKbiZmcy8n3l-mtafrOleart737yar7-HKqvzYwb3TXqZPc6LR1UYpLGyDi4knWqpDZTO3pq8RXeijR9OZ-jXLjNlgUaP5UQ5W4P2hfPWVlfQdWOdn_7f7BvXZ5FCaURjAhFlBGK6JMAoD2WYBAFOmcR4Murecs6DTpIkeBEUE3_L6GpICInHL1039h8)

- -4 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263910/evenly-spread-values/263913?noredirect=1#comment577315_263913) for the famous `~-` trick

Comment: [97](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU1LDoIwFNx7irdssa18NDEmngRZlEixfNrmWRLYcBE3JEbv5G1EcDMzmU_m8XaDv1kzPdX58uq84sePbGSbXyX0p7Te8rHa8bEpDNFUWYSapYHOtIESbefygfRMG79EFcw2SlMWZO3TbKPQtqB9gd7a5g66dRZ98D_iDuctUSQNRcQgFDGDSOwZxCL5waIODBIRZ5Suo2la-Qs)

Comment: What would a non groupby solution look like?

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 64 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8 bytes

```
⌊øĖ₌ɾ›/+f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oyKw7jEluKCjMm+4oC6LytmIiwiIiwiWzAuMSwgMC4yLCAxLjQsIDIuMywgMi40LCAyLjUsIDMuMl0iXQ==)

*-2 thanks to emanresu*

### Explained

```
⌊Ġ:@₌ɾ›/+f­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⌊Ġ          # ‎⁡Group the floored values by consecutive items. 
  :@        # ‎⁢Push a copy of that where each item is the corresponding length. 
    ₌ɾ›     # ‎⁣Push a list [range 1..n for n in top], [n+1 for n in top]
       /    # ‎⁤And divide those lists.
        +   # ‎⁢⁡Add that to the original grouped values
         f  # ‎⁢⁢Then flatten
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [9](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLijIrDuMSW4oKMyb7igLovK2YiLCIiLCJbMC4xLCAwLjIsIDEuNCwgMi4zLCAyLjQsIDIuNSwgMy4yXSJd)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map(k=v=>(k[v|=0]=~-k[v])/~x.filter(t=>~~t==v).length+v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hca7DoMgFADQvV/BCCneIraTufyIYSAWrJWCUUIcGn6dPpaT8zTZ7OM2r6kJ8W6rw3qgOuBlVrpgRkWXIb9RaCzNd5pdygFu9sluNKEqJSFmBt6GKT3OmdX@NMawR2/Bx4k6OghoOREgOWnhyomE7sd/N046kJqxvn4A)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map(k=v=>(k[v|=0]=-~k[v],v)).map(m=v=>v+(m[v]=~-m[v])/~k[v])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDoMgFET3PQVLfgq/iO3KfC9iWBCrTauI0Ya4MF4dhc3My7z52WDXdvnOfzn5dxd7ihvVGzo784EC1Xxowk7KkDwuMiIAZOmSDHfurpEOmQoe@QKxurV@Wv3Y4eg/vOeNwkIwhVqwAp@CaSxTZHoJVqI2AFU8AQ)

Comment: [Alternative 61](https://tio.run/##HYtBDsIgEADvvoIjxGWlVC82Wz/ADxoOTQWj1NJYQ3ow/Tqil5m5zKNP/TK87vNbTvHqcvbEVzCkwNGKz37mgRK1PHTpQ8qS3EpZcZCbKd4nIag1F3f25QoiN7shTkscHY7xxj3vFFbAFGpgFR6Baax/@NcJWI3aCtHkLw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Nġıżnl⁺/+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPU4lQzQlQTElQzQlQjElQzUlQkNubCVFMiU4MSVCQSUyRiUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjAuMSUyQyUyMDAuMiUyQyUyMDEuNCUyQyUyMDIuMyUyQyUyMDIuNCUyQyUyMDIuNSUyQyUyMDMuMiU1RCZmbGFncz1T)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
Nġıżnl⁺/+  # Implicit input
N          # Floor each value
 ġ         # Group consecutive
  ı        # Map over this list:
   ż       #  Without popping, push [1..length]
    nl     #  Length of the current group
      ⁺    #  Incremented
       /   #  Divide the range by this
        +  #  Add to the group
           # Implicit output, flattened
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(p=v=>a.map(V=>v^V||n++,n=1,p!=(p=~~v)?q=1:q++)&&p+q/n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcnLCsIwEEDRX4mbkpDp2KS6Eab@RTeiMNRWlJpHK1mV/np8gJvLgfvgxHM33cOrdP7a54EyU8P45CADpT9batKlXRanNTgyEDb02eua1DGSOUStVVEEHbdO5c672Y89jv4mB3mq0ICo0IIwuANhsf7mpz2IGu1ZqfwG)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                 // a[] = input array
a.map(p =            // initialize p to a NaN'ish value
  v =>               // for each value v in a[]:
  a.map(V =>         //   for each value V in a[]:
    v ^ V || n++,    //     increment n if floor(v) = floor(V)
    n = 1,           //     starting with n = 1
    p != (p = ~~v) ? //     if p is not equal to floor(v)
                     //     (update p to floor(v) afterwards):
      q = 1          //       start a new group with q = 1
    :                //     else:
      q++            //       increment q
  ) &&               //   end of inner map()
  p + q / n          //   the final value is p + q / n
)                    // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 47 bytes

```r
\(x)ave(x,y<-x%/%1,FUN=\(z)seq(z)/sum(1,z^0))+y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHSNAUbXYWlpSVpuhY39WM0KjQTy1I1KnQqbXQrVPVVDXXcQv1sYzSqNItTC4GkfnFproahTlWcgaamdiVUm3qaRrKGgZ6hjoKBnpGOgqGeiY6CkZ4xiACzTHUUjPWMNDUhyhcsgNAA)

Not as short as the [answer using `sequence`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263925/67312), but `ave` is pretty neat, too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
≦⌊θＩＥθ⁺ι∕⊕№…θκι⊕№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYq9CsIwFEZ3n@KON3AN/dGpk1QEB6F76RDSYIMxMUlb8Oljm9VvOHxwjpxEkE6YlB7ic4lRPy3ejHOBwLPm0AVtZ2xFnHHz6Ak6s0TUBFe96lHh3cqg3srOasTWLXv8lUa1k8v1ixFotuG/89nkNSn1fcFLgoJXBCU/EVS83pHfmaDm1TCk42p@) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ                 Input array
≦                   Apply to all elements
 ⌊                  Floor
     θ              Floored array
    Ｅ               Map over floored elements
       ι            Current floored element
      ⁺             Plus
            θ       Floored array
           …        Truncated to length
             κ      Current index
          №         Count of
              ι     Current floored element
         ⊕          Incremented
        ∕           Divided by
                 θ  Floored array
                №   Count of
                  ι Current floored element
               ⊕    Incremented
   Ｉ                Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 61 bytes

```perl
sub{map{//;map{$'+$_/($c+1)}1..($c=grep$'==int,@_)}0..$_[-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNb4JAEL3zKybbTQXcLl9Cq4SUexO99CaGWF2NieAWIdEQfjvdHYlpPLUc3ryd997sZJGiOoZ9cQW6S/pz89UWa9k6TqwLHY1p7ph0M/aszuNcsWRfCUlHSXIoa5bmVudyTvPli7fq@tjYnSrTAPUtEWHpco@By30GHp8w8HmgAVnIIOD@it2dQRBobxRF2h1qjx8OTp@/oj9coX1I/e2WEAWXu4jT6VDudfqvHUJNPXeYOUGMEN@G3QyrRVJcTXooJaPiIq0kpXk8tNP9qU6e6c5MtW7d2thUjw5nx8x4tm2DzuK2Qz2nYijGAE@nppZNDcX6AgFsxeZQrI9njMtK/RAgal5Tz3Cenp2VJP4tq03EphbbmZIVf5TVLZi9bfOoYoSA@FZUyQTegSw@CMyA2LY9X3yCOjEgWYnJzuh/AA)

```perl
sub {
  map {                #loop ints in $_ from 0 to highest input number as int
    //;                #copies current $_ to $'
    $c=grep$'==int,@_; #$c = count of current int in $_ in input array @_
    map {              #loop 1 to current count in $c
      $' + $_ / ($c+1) #return current outer int + inner int / count+1
    }
    1..$c              #inner loop, no loop and no return if count is 0
  }
  0..$_[-1]            #outer loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
=sMQm+c@XdH1d/+Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/37bYNzBXO9khIsXDMEVfO/D//2gDPUMdBQM9Ix0FQz0THQUjPWMQAWaZ6igY6xnFAgA)

#### Explanation

```
=sMQm+c@XdH1d/+QdddQ    # implicitly add Q
                        # implicitly assign Q=eval(input()), H=dict()
=  Q                    # assign Q to
 sMQ                    # floor() mapped over Q
    m              Q    # map lambda d over Q
        XdH1            #   H[d]+=1 (or H[d]=1 if d not in H)
       @    d           #   H[d]
      c                 #   divided by
             /   d      #   the count of how many times d appears in
              +Qd       #   Q with d appended
     +            d     #   plus d
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
<.+&;<.<@(#\%1+#)/.<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09CwIxEER7f8Vg0PNMHPNhIsQIomAlFrZeJx5i4/@v4iUKNha7DPses888ZtNjG9FAQSMOsyAOl9MxJ8rpJjHtZqKbGCnaJRNzOzrvib@skmv83KXo5uaH7rfHCz00zfCGVsFwpWDpyqrJKzja2qHpnCteCKGYvnDrv5bluro@vwE)

Repetition of floor `<.` 3 times was surprisingly shorter than alternatives that DRY it out.

- `<..../.<.` For each group of the floor...
- `<@(#\%1+#)` Divide 1...g by (1 + g), where g is the group size.  Box it `<@` because we have to box heterogeneous lists.
- `<.+&;` Add the floor elementwise to that unboxed result.